# Showing color picker dialog without showing input option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I need to get some color input from the user when they click a particular `div`. The `div` itself is heavily styled and I don't want to ruin its appearance by dropping an `input[type=color]` in it.

Is there a way to programmatically open the native color picker? Is there a way to hide the `input[type=color]` in the `div` (probably with `-webkit-appearance: none`) to make it show a color picker when it is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use something like hide the input using opacity. It means that you would still maintain its click event, without actually showing the colour button itself.

This works since whilst the input is hidden with `opacity:0`, the input is 'still there' and so can still be clicked.

A quick demo would be:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
div input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>CLICK ME
  <input type="color" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i found that using focus() on the input should open the color picker ... but only in supported browsers - what browsers and when isn't said

my chrome wont open the color picker (https://jsfiddle.net/63vjom0x/)

HTML

```
<div id="test">some content<br>
<input type="color" name="farbe" id="farbe"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#test').click(function() {    
    alert("div clicked");
    $('#farbe').focus();
});
```

(https://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/6-color.html)

Comment: not sure if it's jsfiddle or maybe my chrome, but this won't open the color picker?

Comment: as i wrote: it wont open the color picker - it may work in the future

Comment: It works. the problem was `display: none`. Here is the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/63vjom0x/1/